# How to remove ':00' from 'hh:mm:00' in Pandas dataframe column 'Time' from html output?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I have an Excel file, which has a Time column, in which I typed time in `hh:mm` format. But after I did `pd.read_excel`, and `pd.to_html`, they have all become `hh:mm:00`.
How can I remove `:00` from `hh:mm:00`, please?

```
        Date      Time   Remarks More_Details
0 2020-12-31  20:30:00       NaN          NaN
1 2021-01-04  09:05:00       NaN          NaN
```

Comment: You need to make sure you understand the difference between a thing (in this case, an object that represents a time of day) and a representation of that thing (in this case, a string that gets printed in order to show what time is being represented). Just like you need to understand the difference between a thing (in this case, the actual time of day) and a representation of that thing (in this case, an object in your program).

Comment: Oh. How do you remove it, then? I am sorry I am a Python beginner. I have tried it in many ways for quite long, but failed.

Comment: @ShermanChen are all the dates are in this format hh:mm:00?

Comment: You missed the point.  Those cells don't actually have ":00" in them.  The contents of the cell is basically a big floating point number.  It's being displayed that way, but you can display it however you want.

Comment: @PavanSuvarna, yes, they are.

Comment: @TimRoberts Oh. How to display it as hh:mm is what I do not know. :) How, please?

Comment: You should look at your dataframe's `dtypes` to see what that column is.

Comment: @tdelaney The ```dtypes``` of the ```Time``` column is ```object```.

Comment: does this answer your question?
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M')
@ShermanChen

Comment: Good. Test what the object type is. Making assumptions about your names, `type(df['timecolumn'][0])`. Then you can work on that object's display ruless.

Comment: @PavanSuvarna Got ```TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime```

Comment: @tdelaney ```<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>```

Comment: I would have expected `df['timecolumn']` to be a Series and `df['timecolumn'][0]` to be the object of interest. It would help to have an example dataframe we can work with.

Comment: @tdelaney The type of both is ```<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>```. I have put the example dataframe. Please press Ctrl+F5 to refresh your page to see my example.

Comment: @tdelaney Strange! When you let me do ```type(df['timecolumn'][0])```, I did it, and it was ```<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>```. But I did it now, it is ```<class 'datetime.time'>```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem just now

`df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x:str(x)[0:5])`

Answer (score 0):

Use pd.Timestamp to handle your formatted times.

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(pd.Timestamp).dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

Comment: I got  ```TypeError: Cannot convert input [20:30:00] of type <class 'datetime.time'> to Timestamp```